# How can I match this complex pattern with regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables, jquery-select2

I have data such as:

Record 1:

```
Winter 2014 - Barrie, Muskoka
<br style="display: block;">
Summer 2014 - Orangeville, Owen Sound
<br style="display: block;">
Fall 2013 - Barrie
```

Record 2:

```
Winter 2014 - Barrie
<br style="display: block;">
Fall 2013 - Barrie
```

I need to filter it on AND and OR via tags. There is a campus filter and a term filter - in each filter you can select multiple campuses or multiple terms and it needs to filter accordingly.

For example:

```
Campus: Orangeville,Barrie
Term: Summer 2014,Winter 2014
```

The above tags should return both results because the first record has Orangeville listed next to Summer 2014 and the second record has Barrie listed next to Winter 2014.

After some research and testing I think I need something along the lines of below but I can't quite get it to work properly... I'm a bit of a regex beginner.

```
(?=Winter\ 2014\ \-\ (Barrie|Orangeville))(?=Summer\ 2014\ \-\ (Barrie|Orangeville))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you can match it like this:

```
var campuses = ["Barrie", "Orangeville"];
var terms = ["Winter 2014", "Summer 2014"];
```

`var your_regex = new RegExp("(" + terms.join("|") + ")\\s-\\s(" + campuses.join("|") + ")");`

Then test if your record matches:

```
if (your_regex.test(your_record)) {
  // Record matches
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this and report back.